# How can I know/list available options for kernel modules?

Tags: command-line, kernel, modules

As the question says it all, I would just like to elaborate with an example:

`i915.i915_enable_rc6=1`

This is an option for i915 module or intel video driver. So is there any way to know or list something like  `i915_enable_rc6` is an option for `i915` from linux commandline ?

I hope I am clear with the question ?

Edit: I was referring to i915 just for example and nothing else. `modinfo` seems to be the command I was looking for.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

modinfo does it:

```
modinfo i915 | grep '^parm:'
```

For open source modules the most reliable way is to look at the source. You don't need to be a kernel developer.

See [source for i915](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ze679yAWiJU/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_drv.c&q=i915_enable_rc6%20package:linux-2.6%20lang:%5Ec$&type=cs).

Comment: If there is no section called `parm` in the `modinfo` output does that mean there is no options to configure the modules?

Comment: Mostly it means that author wanted to keep it as a non-visible parameter for some reason. See updated post.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 18):

You can find all the applicable i915 kernel params applicable for your card using a command such as

```
sudo grep -H '' /sys/module/i915/parameters/*
```

or

```
sudo grep . /sys/module/i915/parameters/*
```

(thanks @arrange)

In my case I can potentially use:

```
/sys/module/i915/parameters/fbpercrtc:0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6:1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock:1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_use_ssc:1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/modeset:-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave:1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/reset:Y
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores:0
```

If no parameters are identified then either that is a true statement - or the kernel is loading a different kernel module than you were expecting:

```
 sudo lshw -c display

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3050(size=8)
```

In the above trace you can see in the configuration line "driver=i915" that the kernel sees the video card and has loaded the i915 module.

[source](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Comment: +1. I'd just simplify the command to `sudo grep . /sys/module/i915/parameters/*`

Comment: I was referring to `i915` because its mostly used. But the path information was something I didn't know, so if there is no `parameters` folder in the  `/sys/module/{module_name}/` Does that mean the specific module doesnot have options to tweak ?

Comment: @sagarchalise - have updated with an explanation

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this is an [newer modinfo options](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/modinfo.8.html), but modinfo support listing only the parameters:

```
$ modinfo -p i915
```

or

```
$ modinfo --parameters i915
```

Note: the `$` sign is just the prompt display. It shows that the command can be run as a non-root user and without sudo.

It is possible to also check the current parameters of an already loaded modules using [systool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/systool):

`systool` is part of the sysfsutils package. Install it with this command

```
sudo apt-get install sysfsutils
```

Then use it this way

```
$ systool -v -m i915
```

In the output of this command check the "Parameters:" section.